# Lambda on Dictionary Condition

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

Let's say I have a list with a dictionary with and `id`, `score` and `key`. I would like to create a method do return the score given the `key` using lambda functions.

This method suffices the problem:

```
def my_search(txt):
    for i in my_dictionary:
        if i['key'] == txt:
            return i['score']
```

But I'd like to use lambda functions to do that. I've tried to use lambda with a filter, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I proceed?

I have something like

`[{'id': 1, 'score': 8.321, 'key': 'stv'}, {'id': 1, 'score': 6.321, 'key': 'mrk'} ... ]`

Comment: show an example of your dictionary.

Comment: This is not a reasonable place to use a lambda function.  Nothing in Python ever *requires* a lambda, they're just a shortcut for certain simple function definitions (that don't happen to include your function).

Comment: First, there are no methods in this code, only a normal function. To be glib, I'd say just use `lambda txt: my_search(txt)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
def my_search(txt):
    val = list(filter(lambda elem: elem[0] == txt ,my_dictionary.items()))
    return(val[0][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should take a function as an argument, and call the function instead of performing the comparison.

```
def my_search(func):
    for i in my_dictionary:
        if func(i['key']):
            return i['score']

print(my_search(lambda k: k == txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `my_search` to a lambda function using a generator expression like this:

```
my_search = lambda txt: next(i['score'] for i in my_dictionary if i['key'] == txt)
```

so that given:

```
my_dictionary = [
    {'id': 1, 'score': 8.321, 'key': 'stv'},
    {'id': 1, 'score': 6.321, 'key': 'mrk'}
]
```

`my_search('mrk')` would return:

```
6.321
```

Answer (score -1):

```
txt = 'a'
d = {'a':'b'}
>>> [v for k,v in d.items() if k==txt]
['b']
```

Comment: Where is the lambda? Where do you test the `key` entry in the dictionary and return the `score`?